# Used mongoose BMX started having issues with rear sprocket not engaging when pedaling causing safety issue

Tags: wheels, safety, bmx, sprocket, rear

I got a used Mongoose BMX for my son. I know when I was younger Mongoose was halfway decent. But now they kinda stink. Putting that lightly!

Anyway the bike rode well at first, then after a flat tire and innertube change he would start riding and the rear free wheel or sprocket would spin but not the rear tire so my son keeps wrecking the bike! I've tried adding some lube to it and that worked for about a minute!now same issue? What can I do? No extra noises or anything like that.

Comment: Just to clarify, the pedals turn, which moves the chain, which moves the single rear sprocket but that seems to be dis-connected from the rear hub?

Answer (score 1):

If the freewheel isn't working it is possible to take it apart and try to repair it. Chances are good there are no parts for the freewheel so if you get it apart and find that parts need to be replaced it's a throw away. Freewheels usually have the brand stamped on them so a quick search will tell you if there are parts available.

Since the freewheel is relatively inexpensive (and since your current freewheel is old and might be worn) it's probably best to remove it and replace it.
It takes a special tool to remove the freewheel. If you take the wheel off the bike and take it down to the bike shop they may remove it for you for free.